# "Conversion from string "Row E1:2 seats2" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."

Tags: visual-studio-2010

**"Conversion from string "Row E1:2 seats2" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."**

please help
I am making a cinema booking system. I need to be able to book the seats and check the availability of the seats
1-6 seats and a-e row
Form Definition:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim seats(5) As String //'this declares the array seats as string'
    Dim firstseat As Integer //'this declares first seat as integer'
    Dim rowid As Integer //'this declares row id as integer'
    Dim numseats As Integer //'this declares numseats as integer'
    Dim bookseats As Integer //'this declares book seats as integer'
    Dim currentseat As Char //'this declares current seat as char'
```

Other Sub Definition:

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For x = 0 To 4
            seats(x) = "0000000000" 'seats equals 0000000000'
        Next 'moves onto the next stage'
        Button2.Enabled = False ' this means you cannot click button 2'
    End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then 'if combobox 1 equals empty then a message box appears'
        MessageBox.Show("please select a row") 'message box appears showing please select a row'
        Return
    End If 'this ends the if function' 
    If ComboBox2.Text = "" Then 'if combo box 2 equals empty then a message box appears'
        MessageBox.Show("please select seats") ' message box appears showing please select seats'
        Return
    End If ' this ends the if function' 
    If ComboBox1.Text = "A" Then ' if combo box 1 equals A then row id equals 4'
        rowid = 4

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "B" Then ' if combo box 1 equals B then row id equals 3'
        rowid = 3

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "C" Then ' if combo box 1 equals C then row id equals 2'
        rowid = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "D" Then ' if combo box 1 equals D then row id equals 1'
        rowid = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "E" Then ' if combo box 1 equals E then row id equals 0'
        rowid = 0
    End If 'ends the if statement'
    numseats = Val(ComboBox2.Text) 'numseats equals val combobox 2'
    bookseats = 0 'book seats equals 0'
    For i = 1 To 10
        currentseat = Mid(seats(rowid), i, 1) 'current seat equals mid seats rowid i 1'
        If currentseat = "1" Then 'if current equals 1 then'
            bookseats = bookseats + 1 'bookseats equals bookseats plus 1'
        End If 'this ends the if function'
    Next 'moves onto the next stage'                
    If 10 - bookseats < numseats Then 'if 10 - bookseats is less than numseats then'
        MessageBox.Show("no seats available") 'message appears showing no seats available'
    Else 'or'
        For i = 1 To 10

            firstseat = InStr(seats(rowid), "0")
        Next 'move onto the next stage'


        If firstseat = "1" Then
            MessageBox.Show("1 seat selected") 'if first seat is 1 then messagebox appears saying 1 seat selected'
        ElseIf firstseat = "2" Then
            MessageBox.Show("2 seats selected") 'if first seat is 2 then messagebox appears saying 2 seats selected'
        ElseIf firstseat = "3" Then
            MessageBox.Show("3 seats selected") 'if first seat is 3 then messagebox appears saying 3 seats selected'
        ElseIf firstseat = "4" Then
            MessageBox.Show("4 seats selected") 'if first seat is 4 then messagebox appears saying 4 seat selected'
        ElseIf firstseat = "5" Then
            MessageBox.Show("5 seats selected") 'if first seat is 5 then messagebox appears saying 5 seats selected'
        ElseIf firstseat = "6" Then
            MessageBox.Show("6 seats selected") 'if first seat is 6 then messagebox appears saying 6 seats selected'
        End If 'ends the if statement'
    End If 'ends the if statement'
        If 10 >= numseats Then 'if 10 - more than or equal to numseats then'
            MessageBox.Show("seats available") 'messagebox appears showing seats available'
        End If 'ends the if statement'

    If ComboBox1.Text & firstseat & ":" & ComboBox2.Text & (firstseat + numseats - 1) Then
        Button2.Enabled = True
    End If 'ends the if statement'
    If ComboBox2.Text = "1 seat" Then 'if combobox2 equals 1 seat then numseats equals 5'
        numseats = 5
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "2 seats" Then 'if combobox2 equals 2 seats then numseats equals 4'
        numseats = 4
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "3 seats" Then 'if ComboBox2 equals 3 seats then numseats equals 3'
        numseats = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "4 seats" Then 'if combobox2 equals 4 seats then numseats equals 2'
        numseats = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = " 5 seats" Then 'if combobox2 equals 5 seats then numseats equals 1'
        numseats = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = " 6 seats" Then 'if combocbox2 equals 6 seats then numseats equals 0'
        numseats = 0
    End If 'ends the if statement'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't VBScript. Nevertheless,  all Basic dialects need a Boolean expression between the If and the Then of a conditional statement.

Your

```
If ComboBox1.Text & firstseat & ":" & ComboBox2.Text & (firstseat + numseats - 1) Then
```

needs a comparison of the concatenated string against something sensible.

Comment: can you advise me on what to write?

Comment: im making a cinema booking system